# How can we compile OpenHaptics v3.0 with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, compiler-construction, compilation

I want to compile my Haptic Application with Visual Studio 2010 but the Academic Edition of OpenHaptics v3.0 supports Visual Studio 2005 compiler only.

VS2005 doesn't have any problem I can compile and run my application with no issue, but due to other libraries I want to move to VS2010.

Is there any way that I could use VS2010 with OpenHaptics® v3.0. The only problem with hl.lib and hd.lib, I can recompile hdu.lib and hlu.lib with VS2010 successfully but I have no idea how can I compile hl.lib and hd.lib with VS2010.

I have been thinking to use vs2010 since 1 year but still no success, any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the VS 2010 IDE with the VS 2005 build tools if you install Daffodil:
http://daffodil.codeplex.com

Comment: Oh great.. It worked for me. I am not using it but it gave me an idea what can I do more. Thanks alot.